# Imagecolortransparent() for multiple colors

Tags: php, image, png, transparency

I use this code to make all white pixels transparent:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');
$remove = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $remove);
imagepng($img, 'bla.png');
```

But I also want some "almost white" pixels to be transparent like `254, 255, 255` etc. How could I add that?

Comment: Try using "fuzz 1%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to remove a contiguous area with similar color range; I must say that it's hard using PHP's GD library. You should take a look at [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) which is a much more powerful image processing library and has [PHP integration](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

If you choose to use ImageMagick instead, you'll have access to a lot of third-party scripts that does amazing image processings. One of which is Fred Weinhaus' [MagicWand](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/magicwand/index.php). It does what you're looking for.

You seed it with an `x` and `y` coordinate, it can extract the color of that coordinate and make it transparent with a configurable color dissimilarity threshold (fuzz factor). Have a look how it can match a gradient of blue:

[image: magicwand's magic]

Comment: This code only removes 254, 255, 255. Well yeah I need to make the white background of clothes images transparent and removing some specific colors isn't very good solution. What would you suggest in the first place for that?

Comment: The answer hints at using "fuzz".   You want to use a "fuzz" value to tell how close a color needs to be to the target "transparent" color to be affected.  From the commandline it would be "-fuzz 1" or "-fuzz 2".  Surely the PHP binding has some equivalent way of setting the fuzz value.

Comment: @AnneSchwarz: My suggestion, as I said, is to use ImageMagick instead. Also, as far as I see, that [MagicWand](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/magicwand/index.php) script is just what you need. You can use it directly, or port some parts of it to PHP for your own use.

Comment: Ok I downloaded the file from Magicwand which is 12kb and don't have any extension. What the hell do I do with that? Do I need root access to the server which I have rent? I hate such stuff..

Comment: Now I downloaded the file MagickWandForPHP-1.0.9.zip.asc from http://www.magickwand.org/download/php/releases/?C=M;O=D and when I open it with notepad it's like: -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

iQIcBAABAgAGBQJT71hjAAoJEImrY9SCdzd6OpkP/R7SrDk7Y0lSR69xh+jc7Kaj
nSWIGTF7HQhS5Gk2Z2dSnBrxqZP1dkeIEnToZYypaoL4LKIZv2VJvRsxT1LS3vZj WTF is all this CRAP??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. With a black and white image. But white was not very white. So before to set transparency, I do a filter to increase the contrast. And I have an image with real black and real white. And when I use transparency on white color, it's works fine.

Filter's example :

```
imagefilter($src,IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST,-50);
```